# PHP regex to replace 1st line with 2nd line after every empty line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Is it possible to use PHP preg_replace to get the value of each line and replace it with the value of the next line? For example:

```
id "text 1"
str ""

id "text 2"
str ""

id "text 6"
id_p "text 6-2"
str[0] ""
str[1] ""
```

Results in

```
id "text 1"
str "text 1"

id "text 2"
str "text 2"

id "text 6"
id_p "text 6-2"
str[0] "text 6"
str[1] "text 6-2"
```

I use regex but I could not do this one and I am not sure if it's possible or not only with regex.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You say you are using a regex, could you please share it? Also, aren't you just trying to populate the `str` value with the preceding `id` value if `str` value is empty?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: Why are you want to use `preg_replace` for this?

Comment: Is your format like this? I mean 2 lines then an empty always?

Comment: @PatrickMlr what else can I use, since it's about replacing, I thought it's the best one.

Comment: @iliaz yes, it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the blocks capturing the values inside `id` and `id_p` with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/fJ5iS6/2):

```
'~^id\h+"(.*)"(?:\Rid_p\h+"(.*)")?(?:\Rstr(?:\[\d])?\h*"")+$~m'
```

Pass these blocks to the `preg_replace_callback` callback method, and replace the `str ""` and `str[1] ""` with the first capturing group value and `str[1] ""` with the second capturing group value.

Use

```
$re = '~^id\h+"(.*)"(?:\Rid_p\h+"(.*)")?(?:\Rstr(?:\[\d])?\h*"")+$~m'; 
$str = "id \"text 1\"\nstr \"\"\n\nid \"text 2\"\nstr \"\"\n\nid \"text 3\"\nstr \"\"\n\nid \"text 4\"\nstr \"\"\n\nid \"text 5\"\nstr \"\"\n\nid \"text 6\"\nid_p \"text 6-2\"\nstr[0] \"\"\nstr[1] \"\""; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m){
    $loc = $m[0];
    if (isset($m[2])) {
        $loc = str_replace('str[1] ""','str[1] "' . $m[2] . '"', $loc);
    }
    return preg_replace('~^(str(?:\[0])?\h+)""~m', "$1\"$m[1]\"",$loc);
}, $str);

echo $result;
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/8rvT3K)

Comment: it works, thanks. I extended it but it's not working as expected: https://regex101.com/r/pI0cP5/2 can you check?

id -> str[0] and
id_p -> str[1]

Comment: That is not possible with 1 regex pass. You'd need to match blocks and process them separately.

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/mA6dW5/1), are the blocks matched correctly? Is the value you need is the one inside `id_p` in the last block? See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Dwxw8l).

Comment: I think I explained not good enough, please check the updated question. id vale for str[0] and id_p for str[1]

Comment: I do appreciate, awesome

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is always the same, why bother with a regex? A simple loop can do the trick:

```
$ar[] = 'id "text 1"';
$ar[] = 'str ""';
$ar[] = '';
$ar[] = 'id "text 2"';
$ar[] = 'str ""';
$ar[] = '';

for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++){
    if($i%3 == 0){
        $ar[($i+1)] = $ar[$i];
    }
}

print_r($ar);
// Array ( [0] => id "text 1" [1] => id "text 1" [2] => [3] => id "text 2" [4] => id "text 2" [5] => )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the regExp below. Perhaps it helps:

```
<?php

    $string = 'id "text 1"\nstr ""\n\nid "text 2"\nstr ""';
    $rx     = "#([\"'])*([^'\"]*?)([\"'])*(\n\s*?\n*?)(str\s)([\"'])*([^'\"]*?)([\"'])*#si";

    $res = preg_replace($rx, "$1$2$3$4$5$6$2$6", $string);
```